# ASP.Net MVC Recaptcha and Strict Doctype

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, recaptcha

I am using this [this](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2008/12/02/using-recaptcha-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx) Recaptcha approach in my MVC project however it does not validate to Strict 1.0 DOCTYPE.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: what would you like help with?

Comment: to get it to pass the strict doctype validation

Comment: I've just looked at the source and it uses a iframe so its not going to pass anyway. shame.

Comment: I've been advised to use the HTML5 Doctype by someone at recaptcha groups - http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/browse_thread/thread/3c9faec94e96a330

Comment: I've added HTML 5 Doctype and it still fails due to a frameborder property on the iFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own control. As you can see in the RenderContents method of the RecaptchaControl, it use an iframe. Iframe are not HTML strict compliant, thus you have to use a HTML object tag.

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/javascript");
 output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Script);
 output.Indent++;
 output.WriteLine("var RecaptchaOptions = {");
 output.Indent++;
 output.WriteLine("theme : '{0}',", this.theme ?? string.Empty);
 if (this.customThemeWidget != null)
 {
  output.WriteLine("custom_theme_widget : '{0}',", this.customThemeWidget);
 }
 output.WriteLine("tabindex : {0}", this.TabIndex);
 output.Indent--;
 output.WriteLine("};");
 output.Indent--;
 output.RenderEndTag();
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "text/javascript");
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, this.GenerateChallengeUrl(false), false);
 output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Script);
 output.RenderEndTag();
 output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Noscript);
 output.Indent++;
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Src, this.GenerateChallengeUrl(true), false);
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Width, "500");
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Height, "300");
 output.AddAttribute("frameborder", "0");
 output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Iframe); // Change this to object HTML tag
 output.RenderEndTag();
 output.WriteBreak();
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, "recaptcha_challenge_field");
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Rows, "3");
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Cols, "40");
 output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Textarea);
 output.RenderEndTag();
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, "recaptcha_response_field");
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Value, "manual_challenge");
 output.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Type, "hidden");
 output.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Input);
 output.RenderEndTag();
 output.Indent--;
 output.RenderEndTag();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the Microsoft Web Helpers library through NuGet package reference.

Here is a blog post: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=611